# How to ImageRestyle high-res images?

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning, neural-networks, generative-art

I’m running v12 now and `ImageRestyle[]` crashes for me on an image of size 1600 x 1200 pixels.

All the examples in the documentation use images around 500 x 500 or smaller. So, how can I get this to work on high resolution images?

We can't simply map it over sub-windows of the image:

```
p = ImagePartition[i, 100];
ImageAssemble[Map[ImageRestyle[#, s, PreserveColor -> True, 
 PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", RandomSeeding -> 1] &, p, {2}]];
```

[image]

I need to `ImageRestyle` images of 4 or more megapixels in size. Is there someway to get this to use a GPU?

Comment: If we could somehow enforce edge constraints on the sub windows the partitioning idea might work.

Comment: In my `32G` memory machine,I think it is possible.. :)

Comment: I tried using `Inpaint` on the partition edges to smooth them. It's reasonably effective.

Comment: It seems that it is a RAM issue, I mean, how much RAM you have. I was successful with a 1600x1200 image. Oh, I have an iMac with a 12 Gb RAM and running macOS Sierra 10.13, and MMA ver 11.2. Now trying a greater image...

Comment: @M.R. No way for larger images. However, I have tried to downscale the image, then restyle, and, again, to upscale it. The idea can work as the restyling seems to blur the resulting image a bit. So, upscaling should not show a clear detail reduction. Using `ImageResize` in downscaling as well as in upscaling, with a proper resampling, could help to minimize the effect of reducing details.

Comment: “The biggest limitation of Mathematica is that it doesn’t scale well”

Comment: Install the free Wolfram Engine on a big cloud instance. On AWS you can go up to 2 Tera of RAM. Check https://github.com/Ludwiggle/JWLS to connect to a remote kernel

Comment: @Fortsaint "Use a bigger machine" wasn't the answer I'm hoping for lol

Comment: In MMA 12.0, `ImageRestyle` has the (experimental) `TargetDevice -> "GPU"` option, for those who have the supported hardware.  See the Details section of the docs for a [`list of supported HW`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TargetDevice.html)

Comment: Yes that makes it faster but not higher resolution

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to answer this old question, because the issue seems to be resolve in later versions of Wolfram Language.

```
$Version
14.0.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit)
```

I get the following target image:

```
image = Import["https://wolfr.am/1iHhr31lO"]
image // ImageDimensions
```

[image]

and the following style:

```
style=Import["https://wolfr.am/1iHht2RBV"]
style//ImageDimensions
```

[image]

And the following result and timing on purely standard MacBook Pro 6 CPU cores:

```
ImageRestyle[image, style] // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image]

These 2 options are probably best tried always together:

```
PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", 
TargetDevice -> "GPU"
```

You can also try using this neural net, especially see section "Adapt to any size":

https://resources.wolframcloud.com/NeuralNetRepository/resources/AdaIN-Style-Trained-on-MS-COCO-and-Painter-by-Numbers-Data

Automatic image resizing can be avoided by replacing the net encoders. First get the net:

```
net = NetModel[
  "AdaIN-Style Trained on MS-COCO and Painter by Numbers Data"]
```

Extract the original mean channel values:

```
meanRGB = NetExtract[net, "Content"][["MeanImage"]]
```

> {0.48502, 0.457957, 0.407604}

Create the new net encoders with the desired dimensions:

```
netEncC=NetEncoder[{"Image",ImageDimensions[image],"MeanImage"->meanRGB}];
netEncS=NetEncoder[{"Image",ImageDimensions[style],"MeanImage"->meanRGB}];
```

Attach the new net encoders:

```
resizedNet = 
 NetReplacePart[net, {"Content" -> netEncC, "Style" -> netEncS, 
   "Output" -> NetDecoder["Image"]}]
```

Restyle an image using the new resized network:

```
resizedNet@<|"Content"->image,"Style"->style|>
```

[image]