# Quality of ImageRestyle

Tags: image-processing, neural-networks

There is an application of image restyle [here](https://github.com/luanfujun/deep-photo-styletransfer). It is an example in following:

[image]

But if I just use `ImageRestyle` of `Mathematica`

```
in=Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/L2ifw.png"];
style=Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/994ix.png"];
ImageRestyle[in, style, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality",TargetDevice -> "GPU"]
```

[image]

I have to say it is a ugly result. Is there a better method to get an expected result like this?
[image]

Comment: If you run the same example through the deep-photo-styletransfer program yourself do you get their exact results?

Comment: ImageRestyle has weightings options. Did you try changing the defaults?

Comment: Duplicate of https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/156044/how-to-imagerestyle-high-res-images

Comment: @M.R. Duplicate???

Comment: @bills I have tried, acutally it will be same style..[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vLc79.jpg)

Comment: No you're right, it's not a duplicate, one is about 'resolution' the other about 'quality', but the sentiment is similar.

Comment: This question seems to rely heavily on your own sense of what would be a "better" or "pretty" result. So, unless you can pinpoint what you would like to improve, I don't see how the question can be answered meaningfully. Do you know what parameters were used to obtain the image you show?

Comment: @MarcoB I think the result from `mma` produce too many noise. But not just transfer color..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Hi from the main developer of ImageRestyle!

Your comment boils down to comparing two different approaches to deep neural style, namely photorealistic and art-oriented one. The torch code you linked falls into the first category, while `ImageRestyle` belongs to the second.

What you interpreted as noise in your comment is actually the algorithm attempting to provide an artistic, painting-like feeling. Photorealistic style transfer, on the other hand, provides cleaner textures and doesn't bother to introduce artifacts. They are slightly different tools aimed at slightly different tasks.

Unfortunately `ImageRestyle` doesn't currently support a photorealistic method, but we may add it in future releases.

Happy restyling!

Comment: How long is your "in future" roughly?

Comment: Can I expect this upgrade in future releases?

Comment: @yode we have no plans to expand on ImageRestyle currently

Answer (score 5):

I must confess that I feel this question has to do with Arts at some extent. How do we define "better" or "pretty", as @MarcoB point out?

Anyway, I cannot refuse to give my approach, not as a solution, but rather my vision of a "better" or "pretty" image restyle, by playing with options and functions such as `GuidedFilter`.

So let us try with:

```
imrs = ImageRestyle[Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/L2ifw.png"], 
0.45 -> Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/994ix.png"], 
PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"]
```

[image]

I choose `Speed` to not wait for a long time as with `Quality` option. We also can play with the weight `w` (0.45). However, a noticeable change in the final image can be obtained, and it may not be accepted.

However, the final image has some noise as a result of running the process in favor of `Speed`. So taking the original image as the guide, I tried to reduce the noise by means of `GuidedFilter`:

```
GuidedFilter[imrs, Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/L2ifw.png"], 2, 0.001]
```

[image]

Not too bad, isn't it?

Well, time for all of you that want to play.

Oh, please, be advised that the algorithms in which `ImageRestyle` relies change in different versions of the Wolfram Language, yielding different result, as documentation notes.

Comment: I mean, the `mma`'s `ImageRestyle` not also change the color, but also change the original image's outline. It is not my expectation

Comment: @yode That is why you have to play with the weight `w` in the style (see the documentation). You also have to bear in mind that MMA could use different algorithms to restyle the image, different from those used in the software you cited (used)...

Comment: @JoséAntonioDíazNavas Can you try importing the higher quality github referenced network?

Comment: @user5601 I am not sure what you mean...